# NSNetServiceBrowser how to stop, timeout

Tags: ios

What is the standard procedure for ending an NSNetServiceBrowser search?  I'm in the situation where I am looking for one device in particular.  If I don't find the devce, I need to end the search and let the user know that I didn't find anything.  I can't find any timeout option in the online references.  I feel like I am missing something.  What's the way that people typically deal with this issue?